# Adjust SMS length limit?

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I just bought my new Samsung Galaxy S5. When texting, when I exceed 160 characters it automatically converts to MMS. I have researched the remedy,gone to settings and clicked the MMS Alert to 'on' which alerts me when I have exceeded the maximum amount of characters, but it still converts to MMS.  How can I revise the amount of maximum characters so I won't need to use my data? I certainly don't want to have to send multiple texts every time I text over the 160 limit.

Comment: Use WhatsApp or hangouts or similar

Comment: I find it a bit strange that it got converted to MMS. Usually, when the SMS exceeds the size limit, it will be continued as [concatenated SMS](http://www.wikipedia.com/en/Concatenated_SMS), sent as *multiple* SMSes, but not MMS. I don't know if this case is specific to Samsung only or not.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to increase the number of characters you can send via SMS. SMS (Short Message Service) is a fixed standard that is currently defined as a way of sending messages up to 1120 bits in length. This means 160 7-bit characters or 140 8-bit characters or 70 16-bit characters. More here http://www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Service

Comment: That's technically correct, but a protocol to split and reassemble larger messages has been around for many years and is supported by almost every phone since the early 2000s.

Comment: @lxgr while your comment is technically also correct, the protocol is dependant upon the sending device, the receiving device, and the service provider. So a user would have no control over this as they wouldn't have control of the receiver, nor the service provider.

Comment: man, this is the classic problem , if we wrote in 7-bit characters we got 160 characters , on first type of an non-ascii character , you will have 70 characters per sms .

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with my Samsung Galaxy S4. When I exceed 160 characters, it automatically converts the message type to MMS. I installed [Google messenger app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging) to solve this issue.

Comment: good solution google messenger doesn't convert 3 sms to mms !

Answer (score 0):

I found that using a 3rd party messaging app would solve the problem! But then, the functions of the built-in Samsung Messages app would be gone. Such as the swipe to call and also my favourite feature, the quick contacts.

Answer (score -1):

i think you are using s5 prime. With 160 sms limit.there's no way to increase it. But if you root your s5 prime to s5 It can be solve.

Comment: Could you expand your answer by explaining how to achieve that *if the device is rooted*? As of current, it's not so helpful, since (I believe) rooting doesn't automatically remove 160-character limitation on SMS. And what do you mean rooting from S5 Prime to S5?

Comment: Also, what has the device name to do with the 160 byte limit of SMS? As that's a limit in the SMS service itself, how should rooting be able to fix that? It's simply not possible to put more than 160 bytes in a single SMS, as the protocol is setup such.